# Web devtools: inherited styles are displayed with strike-through

Tags: css, devtools

I have a question about web devtools like in chrome or firefox.

```css
.parent {
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.button {
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="button">Bonk!</button>
</div>
```

Using web devtools to inspect the button code, I can see that the following style are strike-through, meaning they are over-ridden.

```
.parent {
    <strike>font-family: 'Lucida Console', monospace;</strike>
    <strike>font-size: 30px;</strike>
}
```

But they are applied by `font: inherit` so why would they be strike-through?

Comment: The are striked-through, _because_ you applied `font: inherit;` on the button. Don’t confuse computed styles, with the display of which property and value got assigned via which rule.

Comment: @CBroe yes i think i get it. `font: inherit;` was more specific.

Answer (score 0):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html):

> Each property may also have a cascaded value of 'inherit', which means that, for a given element, the property takes **as specified value** the **computed value** of the element's parent.

So in your case, the *specified* value will be the *computed* one of the parent. The browser will not apply the default inheritance since you explicitely specified a value thus you have the strike-through but your specified value will do the same job of the default inheritance at the end.